Equivalent to rbind for a loop in sas?
The general idea is to (1) create a subset by stratification (2) run a model by using the subset (3) get the model results (4) do (1)-(3) in loops and rbind them together. I know how to generate the idea in R, but have no idea how to get it in SAS.
The R code is as below：

dd<-data.frame(y=seq(0.1:1,by=0.1),
             base=rep(3,10),
             treat=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
             group1=rep(1:0,5),
             group2=rep(0:1,5),
             group3=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1))

names<-colnames(dd)[4:6] #group1,group2,group3           

result<-NULL 
for (i in 1:length(names)){
  group_num=names(table(dd[names[i]])) #get how many categories in each group
  for(j in 1:length(group_num)){
    subset=dd[which(dd[names[i]]==group_num[j]),] #generate a subgroup of each category in each group
    model=lm(y~base+treat,data=subset) #use the subgroup to run a linear model
    line=c(names[i],group_num[j],model$coefficients) #get the result from the model for each category in each group
    result=rbind(result,line) #finally rbind the result together
  }
}          

The main parts I would like to figure out are:
(1) how to select the group names for stratification through names=colnames(dd)[x1:xn], and then perform a loop(i.e for(i in 1:length(names)) to create the subsets. The real dataset contains over 20 groups, so I prefer to get the group names through something like names=colnames(dd)[x1:xn] instead of listing them one by one in SAS.
(2) how to rbind the line results after modeling in the loop in SAS.

Look at the documentation for Proc REG.  The procedure allows multiple MODEL statements to be specified in a single step.

SAS would be different, definitely need to be using BY processing instead and either ODS tables or OUTEST. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

I don't know enough R to grok your example code, but if you are trying to run the same model on several sub-groups, you would typically do that in SAS with one regression PROC, with a BY statement that identifies the sub-groups.  So given a dataset SASHELP.CLASS with variables Sales, Inventory, and Region, the below code will run linear model with Sales as the dependent variable, Inventory as the independent variable, and will run that for each region subset in the data.  The OUTEST options writes estimates to a new table MyEst.  There are different ways to collect different estimates, depending on what you want.
proc reg data=sashelp.shoes outest=myest ;
  model Sales=inventory;
  by region ;
run ;

